# Stuck at SSH while post-commit on SVN

Tags: svn, ssh

I'm trying to setup a [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) to export files to an existing server.

Because my company server is live and huge has been operating for several years, I cannot `wipe` the whole webserver and do an `SVN update` as the server files are too big and content custom file.

What I want to do now is `commit` on server A and `scp` the latest committed file to server B, so the file would be in the web server direction. I have attempt to do as the following below but fail, any better way to recommend me? I'm not really good on doing configuration.

Here is what I'm attempt to do on post-commit:

```
repository="file:///var/www/html/svn/testrepo/"
revision_from=$2
target_directory="/home/SVN/"

expr $((revision_from--))
rm -R -f $target_directory

for line in `svn diff --summarize -r $revision_from:HEAD $repository | grep "^[AM]"`
do
        if [ $line != "A" ] && [ $line != "AM" ] && [ $line != "M" ]; then
            filename=`echo "$line" |sed "s|$repository||g"`
            # don't export if it's a directory we've already created
            if [ ! -d $target_directory$filename ]; then
                    directory=`dirname $filename`
                    mkdir -p $target_directory$directory
                    svn export --force $line $target_directory$filename
                fi
        fi
done

scp -r -P 1221 /home/SVN/* svnadmin@192.168.0.1:/home/svnadmin/
ssh -t -t -p 1221 svnadmin@192.168.0.1 \
sudo -u apache /bin/cp -rf /home/svnadmin/* /path/to/web/
```

Please let me know if you need extra info~

Edit: Modify the script to latest

Edit2: Now I got this error and it doesn't seems to execute /bin/cp

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Connection to 192.168.0.1 closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding my user to apache group, so that my user can overwrite apache files